# Does command line windows restart gracefully exit running app

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pyinstaller

Platform: Windows 2008 server

Ran into a problem where my one-file exe generated with pyinstaller would not clear its associated temporary folder. Read up about this http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/ and found out if the exe doesn't close gracefully it would not delete its associated temporary folder. After this I spoke to the IT guys who setup the exe and was told that the app is started on system start-up and every night a system reboot occurs.

I tried finding out if the system restart on windows would gracefully exit running applications, but couldn't find anything regarding this.

Does anyone know if windows gracefully exits running apps with a scheduled system restart?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As a general rule, you mustn't depend on applications always being able to exit cleanly.  In this scenario, you should probably clear the temporary folder the next time your application starts up.

Comment: Just as feedback. I had to add a clean up script to the application. The reboot sometimes did not allow the application to exit gracefully which is why pysinstaller did not run the clean-up routines it was suppose to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does, but [implementation slightly differs between XP\Vista](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700677.aspx). You can also change shutdown timer and auto-close behaviour: [How to Specify WaitToKillAppTimeout to Speed Up Shut Down Time in Windows](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/37424-waittokillapptimeout-specify-shutdown-windows.html).

#### In Windows XP:

> In Windows XP, each running application is sent the WM_QUERYENDSESSION
> message at shutdown. Applications can return TRUE to indicate that
> they can be closed, or FALSE to indicate that they should not be
> closed (e.g., because doing so would cause the user to lose data or
> destroy a CD being burned). If an application returns FALSE, in most
> cases, shutdown will be cancelled (and the application that cancelled
> shutdown is sent WM_ENDSESSION with wParam == FALSE).
>
> Applications can also delay responding to WM_QUERYENDSESSION in order
> to display UI asking what the user would like to do. For example, when
> Notepad has unsaved data and displays a "Would you like to save your
> data?" dialog during shutdown, this is what it is doing. By default,
> applications can delay responding to WM_QUERYENDSESSION for up to 5
> seconds. After 5 seconds, Windows XP will display a dialog that
> indicates that the application is not responding and allows the user
> to terminate it. Until the user responds to this dialog, applications
> can block WM_QUERYENDSESSION (and, consequently, shutdown)
> indefinitely.

#### In Windows Vista

> **Ability for users to forcefully shut down**
> In Windows XP, the UI for
> blocking applications allows users to either cancel shutdown or
> terminate the blocking application. If subsequent applications also
> block shutdown, the system displays identical UI for each blocking
> application. This is frustrating for many users, who, when shutting
> down, "just want" their computers to turn off. Windows Vista will
> solve this by allowing users to terminate the blocking application and
> make shutdown "forceful." In a forceful shutdown, Windows will send
> applications WM_QUERYENDSESSION with the ENDSESSION_CRITICAL flag. If
> an application responds FALSE, Windows will continue shutdown instead
> of canceling it, and will send the application WM_ENDSESSION. If an
> application times out responding to WM_QUERYENDSESSION or
> WM_ENDSESSION, Windows will terminate it.
>
> **Silent shutdown cancellations will no longer be allowed**
> In Windows XP,
> applications are allowed to veto WM_QUERYENDSESSION without displaying
> any UI indicating why they need to cancel shutdown. These "silent
> shutdown failures" are highly frustrating to users, who often take a
> minute or two to realize that shutdown has failed because no UI was
> displayed. Windows Vista will eliminate this possibility by displaying
> UI even if an application vetoes WM_QUERYENDSESSION.
>
> Certain types of applications will no longer be allowed to block
> shutdown. At shutdown, Windows Vista will check whether each running
> application is not responding (an application is defined as not
> responding if it has not responded to any of its window messages in
> the last 5 seconds), and, if so, automatically terminate it.
>
> **Windows Vista will also not allow console applications or applications
> that have no visible top-level windows to block shutdown.** In most
> cases, such applications are less important to users at shutdown than
> applications that do have visible top-level windows. If an application
> without a visible top-level window blocks shutdown by vetoing
> WM_QUERYENDSESSION, or takes over 5 seconds to respond to
> WM_QUERYENDSESSION or WM_ENDSESSION, Windows will automatically
> terminate it.
>
> However, if an application with no visible top-level windows uses the
> new API to proactively indicate that it needs to block shutdown,
> Windows Vista will not automatically terminate it, and will instead
> treat it like an application that does have a visible top-level
> window.